# Where did the contents of the ISO file go?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, system-installation, usb

***Tried to set up Dual-boot***

OS: MS Windows 10 x64

I have downloaded the [latest LTS release (20.04.2.0) of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) today. I copied the ISO file to my pendrive, and restarted my computer. I opened up the BIOS settings and selected my USB stick, to make my PC boot from there. I pressed **Save & Exit**, and rebooted my computer again.

Well, here is the problem: My PC froze at the BIOS startup screen, and stayed there for about a minute, then proceeded to load Windows normally. I checked my USB, and the Ubuntu ISO (instead of approx. 3GB) was 0 bytes large. I uncompressed it with WinRar and its folder was completely empty.

Deleting the Ubuntu ISO from the USB fixed the BIOS-screen freeze.

Two questions remain:

- Where did those file from the ISO go?
- Did they ruin my PC?

***P.S.: Sorry for my English***

Comment: Did you make the USB bootable?

Comment: Is [this resource](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/) helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ISO file is not intended to be placed on the drive.  They are bit-to-bit images that are intended to be copied bit-to-bit onto your USB support.

In your case, your USB stick is probably not bootable.

You may want to enjoy software like http://rufus.ie/ rufus to create your bootable USB.  When done all the data on the USB stick are destroyed, and there is no free space...  You may format it back later to the full size.

More complicated Multisystems http://liveusb.info/dotclear/index.php?pages/os enable more than one system per USB and do not destroy the USB datas.

I do not think your computer is destroyed.  You can change back your BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I will probably continue using VirtualBox, though, because destroying my USB doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: The problem is rather your data in Windows...  My advice, buy a USB or a DVD for the Linuxes...

Comment: @Greg, it doesn't destroy your USB thumb drive. You can format it and use it again and again.